# Liferay Dynamic Data List: Redirect to other page after record added

Tags: liferay, redirect, dynamic-data-list

I created a Dynamic Data List form in Liferay at `http://server/web/guest/apply`, it works fine.

After the user fills the fields and press "Publish", I would like to redirect her to `http://server/web/guest/thanks`.

How can I implement this?
I haven't written any code yet (just configuring DDL from Liferay web interface).

Comment: Have you tried `response.sendRedirect(...)`?

Comment: I haven't worked much in DDL but you can override struts-action class responsible for adding DDL and then based on success redirect to custom url in your overridden struts-action class.

Comment: "your overridden struts-action class" <- I haven't overridden anything, actually I haven't written any code, only configuration via the web interface.

Comment: I mentioned you can override struts-action class using hook-plugin. In you custom struts-action class you can write logic for redirection. Refer https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/override-and-add-struts-actions-with-hook-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en for overriding struts-action class